# DISTINCT based on multiple columns

Tags: c#, linq, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have a groupby in linq that looks like this:

```
var grouped = from all in Allergies.Entities.AsEnumerable()


group (Guid)all.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("allergy.new_foodsensitivityid").Value
   by new
   {
       group = all.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("new_group"),
       time = all.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("new_time"),
       desc = all.GetAttributeValue<string>("new_desc"),
       child = (Guid)all.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("kid.contactid").Value,
       childName = (string)all.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("kid.fullname").Value,
       item = (EntityReference)all.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("item.substitutedproductid").Value,
       type = (OptionSetValue)all.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("item.new_type").Value,
   } into g
   select new
   {
       g.Key.group,
       g.Key.time,
       g.Key.desc,
       g.Key.child,
       g.Key.childName,
       g.Key.item,
       g.Key.type,
       allergy = g.FirstOrDefault()
   };
```

I need all entities returned to be distinct, how do I do that?!

Comment: Looks fine to me.  What is it doing wrong?  Is there an error message?

Comment: Its returning lots of duplicate rows as Allergies.Entities was constructed through use of multiple joins.

Comment: OK.  Can you provide some sample data for us to look at?

Comment: I just need it to spit out distinct rows for group, time, desc, child, childName, item, and type.. I just need to know where to throw the .Distinct method..

Comment: The `group` should already be doing what you want.  However, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/489421

Comment: I feel what Alan want is a combination of SelectMany and an IEqualityComparer implementation for .Distinct()